# Patching complete todos in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to add the ability to complete a todo item by patching in :complete method. Is it possible to use a checkbox for this rather than the link_to I have below? I would very much like a checkbox so it feels like the task is ticked off.

My View

```
<%= link_to "Mark as complete", complete_todo_path(todo.id), method: :patch %>
```

My Controller

```
def complete
  @todo.update_attribute(:completed_at, Time.now)
  redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: "Todo item completed"
end
```

My Resources

```
resources :todos do
 member do
     patch :complete
 end
end
```

EDIT:

I have gone about this another way but now face a different problem...

I have migrated a :completed boolean, I then added it to my form like so (simple_form)

```
<%= f.input :completed, as: :boolean %>
```

This allows me to update completed, not completed.

But how do I get this to show in my view? I don't want to have to click into each todo(edit) I want to do it from the index but not sure how to go about this?

Comment: You current code(using a `link_to`) is the best way to serve your purpose. checkbox returns either 0 or 1 which are suitable for only boolean values which is not the same in your case.

Comment: Is it possible to revert my last migration where I added this and change to boolean?

Comment: Yes it is possible but I don't recommend it because checkbox needs a form to send the values.

Comment: Hmm I see, and how about something like this?
<%= check_box_tag dom_id(todo), todo.id, todo.completed_at.nil? %>
with jquery propping checked and unchecked?

Comment: You could use link_to and then style the link accordingly. I've used font awesome icons to do that.

Comment: I thought about that -- but I want the tick like http://materializecss.com/forms.html checkboxes :/ don't think I can do it without an input, or is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

From a RESTful standpoint there is no need for an additional route here.

Instead your would simply send a `PATCH` request to the normal member route:

```
PATCH /todos/:id, { todo: { complete: true } }
```

Also you want to do it like a real rockstar you might want to use a enum instead of a boolean:

```
class AddStatusToTodo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :todos, :status, :integer, default: 0, index: true
    remove_column :todos, :complete
  end
end
```

---

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:incomplete, :complete, :removed] #etc
end
```

This lets you setup many states without creating several boolean columns and gives you a bunch of functionality almost for free.

To set this up on the view side you could simply create a form for each element:

```
<% @todos.each do |todo| %>
  <%= form_for(todo) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :status %>
    <%= f.check_box(:status, class: 'complete-todo') %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

We could use a classical submit button here but to give a good UX we want to use ajax. Having a form element gives us the perfect foundation since we can simply enhance its behavior:

```
// Setup jQuery to send the csrf-token
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
      var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
    }
});

// Handle clicks on the checkbox and send patch request in background
$().on('click', '.complete-todo', function(event){
  var $input, $form, promise;
  $input = $(this);
  $form = $input.closest('form');
  promise = $.ajax($form.attr('action'), {
    method: 'PATCH',
    data: {
      todo: {
        status: $input.is(':checked') ? 'complete' : 'incomplete'
      }
    }
  });
  // setup callbacks as needed
  promise.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log('Excellent!', data, textStatus, jqXHR);
  });
  promise.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log('Oh Noes!', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
  });
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this very detailed answer! I'll give it a try now - do I have to revert what I have done before trying this?

Comment: It depends - the migration in there will remove the `complete` column. You may need to adjust depending on what your db schema looks like.

Comment: Quick question -- where do I put PATCH /todos/:id, { todo: { complete: true } }? And after putting it into the view it repeats "Status" 12 times on each one? Would you mind pointing me in the right direction? Sorry to be a pain

Comment: `PATCH /todos/:id, { todo: { complete: true } }` is not actually code. Its a common way to document API's.

Comment: ah I see... sorry this is my first project and I'm learning with it, could you possibly point me in direction of somewhere I can read more about your answer?

Comment: You might want to hide the label with CSS - except for screenreaders. You can also customize the value directly or by using I18n module. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label